# Find duplicate entries in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I have accidently imported some documents, which now have duplicate "slugs" .

I am working with `mongoid`, so my model Looks like this:

class MyModel
  field :name, String # "My Object name"
  field :slugs, Array # ["my-object-name"]
end

Where slugs holds an array of strings. But some are duplicates, which should not be.

How to build a query to search for duplicates in arrays?

This is my actual approach, but its results holds ALL of my entries, which is not true

```
    results = MyModel.unscoped.collection.aggregate([
       {"$match" => {"count" => {"$gt" => 1}}},
       {'$group' => {"_id" => "$slugs", 
                     "count" => {"$sum" => 1}}}])
```

Can someone suggest me a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

You need a `$match` after `$group` stage and `$unwind` `slugs` to apply grouping on each slug element.

```
MyModel.unscoped.collection.aggregate([
       {$unwind => "$slugs"}, 
       {$group => {_id => "$slugs",
            count => {"$sum" => 1}}}, 
       {$match => {count => {"$gt" => 1}}}
])
```

This will give you all the duplicate slug elements across entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

My exact query looks like this:

```
results = MyModel.unscoped.collection.aggregate(
         [{"$group" => 
                   {_id: {"_slugs" => "$_slugs"},
                    recordIds: {"$addToSet" => "$_id"}, 
                    count: {"$sum" => 1}
                   }
            },
          {"$match" => {count: {"$gt" => 1} } } 
          ])
```